# Running through every possible value of string in C?

Tags: c

How do I run through every possible value of a string in c? This **includes** characters like '&', '%', or '/'.  For instance, a 3-character string could be "aaa", "a$f", "acg", etc.

Comment: Almost the same way as how you would implement a big integer addition.

Comment: Like? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. Could you please explain it in more detail? Do you mean that you want to iterate over the string and test if the character in it belongs to a certain set or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm not sure about the range (control character? extended-ASCII? beyond?), but regardless, you can just add 1 to the first character and propagate to the last (example of the range a-z): a --> b --> ... z --> (z + 1 over range, change to a, remember the carry and propagate to next) aa --> etc.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, that's what I would like.  Could you please post an example of that?

Comment: I think that he means that he wants every possible string so I imagine he will need to use permutations. You can find a good example of how to implement one here http://www.freewebs.com/permute/quickperm.html ahd here http://www.quickperm.org/

Comment: Why are you needing to do this? If you go too far over 5 or 6 characters you quickly get into territory where you're talking thousands of years for computation. I did a project like this once except for with bits. iirc it was completely unreasonable after 64 bits.

Comment: Write a function `a()` that generates a set of strings by appending each character in your character set to a given string. Write another function `b()` that generates a set of strings by applying `a()` to every string in a given set of strings. Apply `b()` to the empty string, and then to it's own output, and again to that output, and so on until you generate the set you want or run out of memory. For extra credit, prove that every string in the generated set is unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a limit upfront, and the limit is low, you can use nested loops. For example, for thee-character strings use three nested loops, like this:

```
char str[4] = "---";
for (str[0] = ' ' ; str[0] <= 'z' ; str[0]++) {
    for (str[1] = ' ' ; str[1] <= 'z' ; str[1]++) {
        for (str[2] = ' ' ; str[2] <= 'z' ; str[2]++) {
            printf("%s\n", str);
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not know the length upfront, you need to use recursion. The idea is to implement one loop in each level of recursive invocation, terminating when you are at the desired depth.

```
char *str = new malloc(n+1);
str[n] = '\0';
all_strings(str, n-1);

void all_strings(char *str, int n) {
    if (n == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    } else {
        for (str[n] = ' ' ; str[n] <= 'z' ; str[n]++) {
            all_strings(str, n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need recursion, any more than you need it to enumerate the integers ... which is what this calls for, in a large base.

Comment: @JimBalter True, except the base in this case is rather large :) I also think that applying nested loops or recursion requires less mental effort to understand in exchange for having to write more code (and losing a little bit of efficiency along the way).